# Iterating / printing object of arrays into HTML while keeping order in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, object

I have this object of arrays with data about appointments:

[image]

So essentially it is a collection of dates (the keys) with an array of objects. Every element in the array is an object of appointment data like Day, Subject, Client and Duration. So december 2 has two appointments, while 9 december has three, etc.

I want to display to iterate through it and display it in this table format:

[image]

but trying to display it using following HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let detail of details"   class="card-body">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>  Day </th>
  <th>Duration</th>
  <th> Subject</th>
  <th>Client</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr *ngFor="let detaill of detail">
  <td> <small>{{detaill.day}}</small></td>
  <td> <small>{{detaill.duration}} </small> </td>
  <td><small>{{detaill.subject}}</small> </td>
    <td><small>{{detaill.client}} </small></td>
  </tfoot>
```

it gives me this error:

`Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

i tried to transform them into arrays, with `Object.entries(appointments)` but doing so, it messed up the order of the dates.

What can I do to display the table as I wish?

Comment: You need to formulate an array using your original data object. Then you can perform a *ngFor loop from html side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting your data object into a new array of objects may helpful for you to perform a *ngFor loop and get your task done I guess. This code segment may useful to format the original data object.

```js
// Let's assume your original data object is as follows
const obj = {
    '02/11/2020': [
        {
            duration: 4,
            subject: 'Meeting',
            client: 'Bob'
        },
        {
            duration: 6,
            subject: 'Review',
            client: 'Anna'
        }
    ],
    '03/11/2020': [
        {
            duration: 5,
            subject: 'Review',
            client: 'Rob'
        }
    ]
};

// Find keys and values (as two separated arrays)
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
const values = Object.values(obj);

// Now formulate the new array
const formattedObj = [];
keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    formattedObj.push({
        day: key,
        records: values[index].map(value => ({
            day: key,
            ...value
        }))
    });
});

// Let's test it
console.log(formattedObj);
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not grouped by day anymore?

Comment: Can you try it now!

Comment: it works, but how can I order it by 'day' ?

Comment: Did you came up with a solution? Or shall I update my code? You can just sort the keys array that I mentioned above before that keys.forEach.

Comment: yes , i had marked yours as the solution. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to reformat your data. just change your template to :-

```
<div *ngFor="let detail of details|keyvalue"   class="card-body">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>  Day </th>
  <th>Duration</th>
  <th> Subject</th>
  <th>Client</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr *ngFor="let detaill of detail.value">
  <td> <small>{{detaill.day}}</small></td>
  <td> <small>{{detaill.duration}} </small> </td>
  <td><small>{{detaill.subject}}</small> </td>
    <td><small>{{detaill.client}} </small></td>
  </tfoot>
```

Comment: do I need to import or install anything before? because its giving the same error still

Comment: did you use keyvalue pipe like i did and detail.value in inner loop?

Comment: a stackblitz please?